# Getting org.apache.jorphan.logging.Slf4jLogkitLogger overrides final method error while using maven jmeter plugin 2.7.0

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

We have used Ultimate Thread group in our Jmeter test plan. Currently, we are looking to execute the test using maven jmeter plugin.

I am getting following error while trying to run jmeter test using jmeter-maven-plugin version 2.7.0:

```
    [INFO] An error occurred: class org.apache.jorphan.logging.Slf4jLogkitLogger overrides final method log.(Lorg/apache/log/Priority;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.556 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-17T15:15:12-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.7.0:jmeter (test) on project chilapis: Test failed with exit code:1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.7.0:jmeter (test) on project chilapis: Test failed with exit code:1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Test failed with exit code:1
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.testrunner.TestManager.executeSingleTest(TestManager.java:179)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.testrunner.TestManager.executeTests(TestManager.java:115)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.RunJMeterMojo.doExecute(RunJMeterMojo.java:61)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.mojo.AbstractJMeterMojo.execute(AbstractJMeterMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...
```

Following is my POM.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.honeywell.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>chilapis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Default Properties for Project -->
    <properties>
        <jmeter.analysis.maven.plugin.version>1.0.6</jmeter.analysis.maven.plugin.version>
        <jmeter-maven-plugin.version>2.7.0</jmeter-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Profile to run -->
        <profile>
            <id>performance</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- execute JMeter test -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jmeter-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jmeter</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <jmeterVersion>3.3</jmeterVersion>
                            <testPlanLibraries>
                                <testPlanLibrary>org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25</testPlanLibrary>
                            </testPlanLibraries>

                            <!-- <downloadJMeterDependencies>false</downloadJMeterDependencies> -->
                            <!-- <downloadLibraryDependencies>false</downloadLibraryDependencies> -->

                            <excludedArtifacts>
                                <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
                                <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
                                <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclusion>
                                <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-ext</exclusion>
                                <!-- <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion> -->
                                <exclusion>logkit:logkit</exclusion>
                                <exclusion>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j</exclusion>
                                <exclusion>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl</exclusion>
                            </excludedArtifacts>

                            <jmeterExtensions>
                                <!-- <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.5</jmeterExtension> 
                                    <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-graphs-additional:2.0</jmeterExtension> 
                                    <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-synthesis:2.1</jmeterExtension> <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-graphs-basic:2.0</jmeterExtension> 
                                    <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.1</jmeterExtension> -->
                                <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.5</jmeterExtension>
                                <!-- <jmeterExtension>kg.apc:cmdrunner:2.1</jmeterExtension> -->
                            </jmeterExtensions>

                            <remoteConfig>
                                <startAndStopServersForEachTest>true</startAndStopServersForEachTest>
                                <startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
                                <serverList>$serverlist</serverList>
                                <!-- <stopServersAfterTests>true</stopServersAfterTests> -->
                            </remoteConfig>

                            <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
                            <!-- <resultsFileFormat>csv</resultsFileFormat> -->
                            <customPropertiesFiles>
                                <customPropertiesFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/jmeter/custom.properties</customPropertiesFile>
                            </customPropertiesFiles>
                            <testFilesIncluded>
                                <jMeterTestFile>${testsToInclude}</jMeterTestFile>
                            </testFilesIncluded>
                            <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${jmeter.analysis.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>analyze</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source file that contains jmeter result data. Needs to be XML 
                                format or a GZIPed XML format -->
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*</source>
                            <!-- directory where to store analysis report files. At least a file 
                                "summary.txt" will be stored here. -->
                            <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/reports</targetDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins> 

            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Please help in finding the issue in the above pom.xml file. It seems the jmeter jorphan jar is conflicting with other Slf4j jar files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking into your log message, it is not an error, it has [INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#info-java.lang.String-) severity so you're looking into wrong place. The message is due to your test is using [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) which rely on previous logging subsystem (logkit) and since [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) SL4J and Log4j2 are being used.

   ```
   [INFO] An error occurred: class org.apache.jorphan.logging.Slf4jLogkitLogger overrides final method log.(Lorg/apache/log/Priority;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
   ^^^^^^
   ```
2. Looking into [JMeter Maven Plugin source code](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/e1a10b1ff6e53a55f96ea540e2199b47bc0ac342/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/jmeter/testrunner/TestManager.java#L179)

   ```
   if (jMeterExitCode != 0) {
       throw new MojoExecutionException("Test failed with exit code:"+jMeterExitCode);
   }
   ```

   So your JMeter test simply fails (not because of logging). Check out *jmeter.log* file under `target/jmeter/logs` directory - most probably it contains the root cause of the problem in your test.

Comment: Thank Dmitri for your reply. I am trying to run by jmeter test using maven plugin. Could you please point me to where it will generate jmeter.log file. Thanks in advance.